# ffmpeg Fails to download segment

Tags: ffmpeg, youtube-dl

When I download a m3u8 video file with ffmpeg I'm getting this error "Failed to open segment 791 of playlist 0" on some segments. Ffmpeg skips segment 791.How can make ffmpeg not skip the segment.

The segments that the error occurred are missing in the full downloaded video. example if the video full video is 60seconds the downloaded video will be 58seconds when the error occurs.

How can I make ffmpeg keep retrying until it downloads the missing segment 791?

Comment: Did you update `youtube-dl` just before trying to use it? This package needs frequent updates. Please [edit] your question adding the version of YouTube-dl  and maybe your OS.

Comment: Yes I did update it it is the recent version.

Comment: İt seems that ffmpeg is the problem not ytdl